# ASP C# Dynamic Sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Trying to build a (very) simple shopping cart. I did this in PHP using Sessions, which from what I can tell is a little different than ASP Sessions. For starters, PHP sessions are simply server-side cookies. In ASP C# I have found that they reset themselves when you close out of the application. However that's fine for what I am trying to do. But I have come to a road block because I can't figure out how to create a dynamic session that I can add to at any point.

What's baffling me is that if I did just this with a cookie, it would be much different:

```
    public ActionResult TestSession()
    {
        List<int> ids = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        Session["myIds"] = ids;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult TestSession2()
    {
        List<int> ids = new List<int> { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
        Session["myIds"] = ids;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Now I am testing these with a simple a tag in my MVC view:

```
                        <a href="@Url.Action("TestSession", "Products")" class="AddLink"><button class="btn btn-default"> Add to Cart </button></a>    
                        <a href="@Url.Action("TestSession2", "Products")" class="AddLink"><button class="btn btn-default"> Add to Cart </button></a>
```

bringing back the point that is confusing me is that when I debug, Session["myIds"] only holds the value of what it clicks. If I click the first one, then myIds will be 1,2,3,4,5 and if i click the second one, then it erases the first one and does 11,12,13,14,15.. Which is completely contrary to PHP sessions. Now if I did this with a ASP cookie (not sure if I can insert a List into a cookie anyways) then it would stick fine.

So my question is how can I create a session that I can simply add to but doesn't delete the values before? I did try to create a global session but couldn't quite understand how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session is simply a dictionary. You aren't creating a new session (no such thing as dynamic session). When you do `Session["myIds"] = ids;` you're creating a new key in the dictionary (if it doesn't exist) and setting the value to `ids`. If the key already exists in the dictionary, you're overwriting the value. That's why you're getting the behavior you're seeing.

If you wanted to add the elements into the existing list stored in the session, it'd be something like this:

```
if (Session["myIds"] as List<int> != null)
{
    (Session["myIds"] as List<int>).AddRange(ids);
}
else
{
    Session["myIds"] = ids;
}
```

Comment: AH! Okay thanks! Great answer. But this is a dynamic session, no? Either way, thanks a lot man!

Comment: No, as I said there is no such thing as a "dynamic session". There is a single Session object for each [session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx). The session state is stored in the server memory (or it can be configured for a database), and the server knows which session belongs to which connection because of a cookie that contains the Session ID (or if cookieless sessions are enabled, then it stores Session ID in the URL).

Comment: Yeah but dynamic just means it's not static, and by doing your method, that's by definition dynamic since we are adding to it after we declare it.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. But "dynamic Session" or "static Session" is not a common phrase you hear. You just simply refer to it as Session.

Comment: yeah I think I'm not understanding sessions correctly then, appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Session in ASP.NET is simple dictionary - key-value store. 
So what are you doing is simply overwriting value with new value.
Instead of overriding you can simply do something like this:

```
       public ActionResult TestSession()
    {
        List<int> ids = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        if (Session["myIds"] as List<int> != null)
        {
            (Session["myIds"] as List<int>).AddRange(ids);
        }
        else
        {
            Session["myIds"] = ids;
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult TestSession2()
    {
        List<int> ids = new List<int> { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
        if (Session["myIds"] as List<int> != null)
        {
            (Session["myIds"] as List<int>).AddRange(ids);
        }
        else
        {
            Session["myIds"] = ids;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

You have to first check if `Session["myIds"]` is exactly what you expect (`List<int>`) and is not null, then you just have to add your ids to the list.

I suggest reading about [C# collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx).

Comment: yeah, the first guy said this already so i have to give it to him, but upvoting your answer, and thanks for the collections reference. Will look into that.